# How do I import songs from another partition with Rhythmbox?

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, rhythmbox

I currently have songs on another linux partition that I have mounted.  In Ubuntu 11.04, classic version, I can import music folder with Rhythmbox from other partitions with no issues.

After upgrading to 11.10 and clicking on `Import Folder` from Rhythmbox, I can browse to the songs from the other partition but they are all greyed out.  If I browse to that partition with the regular file browser, the songs plays fine.

Is there a way to allow Rhythmbox to import songs from other partitions in 11.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your partition in NTFS format? If so, you are possible dealing with read-only files. I would guess that Rhythmbox displays them as greyed out because it plans on eventually modifying the metadata of the songs - which is not possible with read-only files.
Media players normally only read the file while its playing, but attempt not to write anything to them.

If your partition is in NTFS format and consequently not writable, you should download the `ntfs-3g` package, which allows writing data to ntfs drives and is supposedly better in many other ways than the default ntfs filesystem handler package.

You would do so by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

After this, a remount of the partition would be enough.

Otherwise, please report which filesystem does your partition have, which is a critical thing to know before solving this question

Comment: The strange thing is that I can import those exact same folders from Banshee with no issues.  I guess I'll just use Banshee from now on.

Comment: Did you try installing `ntfs-3g`?

Comment: Not yet.  I think I'll just use Banshee, there's too much tinkering going on with 11.10 to use it as I want.

Comment: Why would a media player require the ability to modify my music files, without even asking me?  Scary.